# Nginx: location rewrite directive not catching desired path

Tags: nginx, configuration

The site I'm working on generates a URL like below for the CSS file.

```
www.example.com/ca/pub/static/version123/styles.css
```

It returns 404 because the `version123` portion is dynamic and generated somehow, and there's no corresponding directory for it. I'm trying to see if I can configure Nginx so that the above URL fetches the same file this URL does.

```
www.example.com/ca/pub/static/styles.css
```

`style.css` is located at `/pub/static/styles.css`.

Nginx location blocks look like this so far.

```
location /ca/pub {
    alias /pub; # this seems to work

    # Supposed to remove the 'version123' portion but doesn't work
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

}
```

The outer block directive seems to be working as I can load the CSS through `www.example.com/ca/pub/static/styles.css`. However, I'm not sure about the nested location. How do I configure it so that when I enter `www.example.com/ca/pub/static/version123/styles.css` in the browser, the CSS file is returned?

Also noticed that without `~`, the configuration is invalid.

```
nginx: [emerg] location "^/static/version" is outside location "/ca/pub"
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Tim I added some words to the first two sentences, but I don't think it can be more clear. What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: You haven't stated the problem you're trying to solve. I suspect you're trying to make a file available on two URLs, or a different URL from the path on the file system. If this is the case you could give the file path, the current URL, and the desired URL.

Comment: @Tim I rewrote it with file path and URLs!

Comment: That makes more sense. I wonder if you can use a location that matches the url "location /ca/pub/static/version123" with just a root directive inside.

Answer (score 0):

Your nested location is invalid as the `^` only matches URIs that begin with `/static` and all of these URIs begin with `/ca/pub/static`. Your `rewrite` statement is invalid for the same reason.

All you need is a [`rewrite` statement](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) that forms a new URI, from whatever follows the `/version.../` string. It may be efficient to wrap this inside a [`location` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) so that the regular expression is only evaluated where necessary:

```
location /ca/pub {
    alias /pub;
}
location /ca/pub/static/version {
    rewrite /version\d*/(.*)$ /ca/pub/static/$1 last;
}
```